# Add users as group members with Microsoft Graph Api in Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

In my project I'm using the Microsoft Graph Api in my Net Core 3.0 project to connect to Azure Intune and add groups and users. When adding a group with members, the graph api requires a json representation of users, like this ( [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-body)):

```
var group = new Group
{
    // other properties omitted
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"owners@odata.bind", "[\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/26be1845-4119-4801-a799-aea79d09f1a2\"]"},
        {"members@odata.bind", "[\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ff7cb387-6688-423c-8188-3da9532a73cc\",\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/69456242-0067-49d3-ba96-9de6f2728e14\"]"}
    }
};
```

**Brief edit:**
I tried the code above from the docs, replacing the Guids with the users I want to add, and this didn't work either, giving me the same error message.
**End edit.**

How do I add the members dynamically in the dictionary, say from an array of user-id's? They seem to use escape characters, and using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayObjectWithIds)` doesn't seem to work, since I get an inproperly formatted OData field back from the Graph Api: `Invalid URL format specified in @odata.bind for members`

What i have:

```
string[] memberIds = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/123", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/456", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/789" };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(memberIds);

newGroup.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"members@odata.bind", json }
};

// Send it off and get Invalid URL format specified in @odata.bind for members error
```

This is my json as it is currently attached to the dictionary:

```
["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/123\"","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/456\"","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/789\""]
```

What is a proper way to put the member uri's into the dictionary object?

Comment: What is the detailed error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was caused by the escape character `\"` in the code, I test the same code from the document and also see the same error message `Invalid URL format specified in @odata.bind for members`. So I modified my code as below:

```
var additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"owners@odata.bind", new List<string>()},
        {"members@odata.bind", new List<string>()}
    };
(additionalData["members@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxx");
(additionalData["owners@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxx");

var group = new Group
{
    Description = "Group with designated owner and members",
    DisplayName = "huryNewGroup",
    GroupTypes = new List<String>()
    {
        "Unified"
    },
    MailEnabled = true,
    MailNickname = "operations2019",
    SecurityEnabled = false,
    AdditionalData = additionalData
};
```

Running the code, I created the group with members successfully.

By the way, we may run into the permission problem. At first I only added the permission `Group.ReadWrite.All` for the app but it shows I don't have permission when I run the code. Then I added the other permissions `Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, it works fine.(As far as I know, there are some minor problems with the `Group` permissions, so you'd better add the other `Directory` permissions)

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thank you @hury-shen, I have been trying for weeks to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has the same issue with the Java example, switch from JsonPrimitive to a JsonArray.

So instead of using Microsoft's example code:

```
        group.additionalDataManager().put("members@odata.bind", 
        new JsonPrimitive("[\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}\",
        \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}\",
        \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}\"]"));
```

Use something like this:

```
        JsonArray arrayOfUsers = new JsonArray();
        arrayOfUsers.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id1}";
        arrayOfUsers.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id2}";
        group.additionalDataManager().put("members@odata.bind", arrayOfUsers );
```